# Задача с Codeforces: Хэш массива

Tags: c++

Ссылка на задачу: https://codeforces.com/gym/102569/problem/A
Выдает ошибку о превышении ограничения по времени на тесте 23, не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь код не имеет ни единого цикла, помимо тех, что участвуют в вводе данных.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n, a, q, l, r, v, h = 0;
    int ind = 1;
    cin >> n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) ind = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a;
        h += a * ind;
        ind *= -1;
    }
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        cin >> l >> r >> v;
        if ((r - l) % 2 == 0) {
            if ((n - r) % 2 == 0) h += v;
            else h -= v;
        }
        cout << h << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Первое, что бросилось в глаза - добавьте в конце main возврат: `return 0;`, также попробуйте чуть изменить вывод: вместо `cout << h << endl;` используйте `cout << h << "\n";` (между `endl` и `"\n"` есть маленькое различие, которое может вам сильно навредить именно на времени выполнения программы).

Comment: @zcorvid к сожалению, не помогло

Comment: а ввод точно ожидается через cin?

Comment: В задаче говорится, что ввод стандартный. Тем более, при неверном вводе скорее всего выдавалась бы другая ошибка

Comment: @user390182 , попробуйте ради эксперимента ещё заменить все `int` на `long long` (счётчики `i`  в циклах и `ind`), скажите, что-то изменилось?

Comment: @zcorvid ничего не поменялось

Comment: добавьте в самое начало программы, `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
 cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);`, это ускорит ввод, и замените `endl` на `'\n'`, endl ещё `flush` делает, что довольно медленно

Comment: @IR42 о мой бог, вы гребаный волшебник, полное решение. Большое спасибо, а не подскажете, что означают эти строки?

Comment: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/5217?locale=ru, описано в разделе **Что это за оптимизации?**

Comment: @IR42 еще раз спасибо